# How long does it take to recieve bit coins?

Tags: bitcoind

I sent bitcoin almost 30 mins ago and still haven't received them yet how long does it take [image]

Answer (score 0):

The amount of time it takes for your transaction to be processed all depends on the rate at which blocks are being mined.

When you spend your bitcoins, they go into the mempool, a place where all incoming transactions wait to be picked up by miners and put into a block. Sometimes, your transaction can get verified immediately, just because a miner is lucky and finds the golden nonce extremely fast. Other times, it can take miners tens of minutes to find the nonce.

While this probably does not apply to your case, if you are spending a large quantity of bitcoins to purchase an item from a vendor, the vendor will often wait till your transaction is 6 blocks deep in the chain to make sure it does not get orphaned or someone attempted to create a fraudulent chain.

Comment: Hello James, thanks for your answer. What do you mean with "the rate at which blocks are being mined"? The individual block may come quicker or slower, but the rate resets to an average of 10 minutes and is practically fixed thusly.

Comment: Hi Murch, what I am saying is that if the network is mining blocks quickly, before the difficulty increases, your transaction will be confirmed quicker. On the other hand, lets say like this recent difficult drop, from 712 to 709 according to TradeBlock, transactions would be over 10 minutes on average. Also, if, by chance, it takes like 50 minutes to mine a block (just unlucky guessing), your transaction will not be confirmed until that block is mined. Hopefully I was correct in my explanation but feel free to edit my response if you feel I was mistaken :).